# Selenium check value of an element's cousin

Tags: java, selenium

This is the html structure, keep in mind that there are multiple articles.

```
<article>
 <div class="inner-article">
  <a style="height:150px;" href="STUFF HERE">
    <img width="150" height="150" src="Some more Stuff" alt="Stuff1">
   </a>
  <h1>
    <a class="name-link" href="STUFF"> Item </a>
   </h1>
  <p>
    <a class="name-link" href="STUFF"> Color </a>
   </p>
  </div>
</article>
```

How would i find the item of the specified color?

Comment: Your question is not clear. You need to update it with actual colors and so on, what you are looking for, and where is your code? Post your code, any error messages, and why it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successfully resolved this by using a java method.

```
 public static WebElement FindItemByItsColor(String item, String color) { 
        return driver.findElement(By.xpath("id('container')/article/div/h1/a[contains(text(), '"+item+"')]/../../p/a[contains(text(),'"+color+"')]")); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you would like to get anchor tag with heading 1. Use following xpath to find your element

"//a[@class='name-link' and contains(text(),'Y')]/../preceding-sibling::h1/a"

Comment: I also need to find X, not only Y.

Comment: Do you want to find element  with class="inner-article" having 'X' and 'Y' as cousins, since they are not siblings. Because 'X' is having parent 'h1' and 'Y' having parent 'p'.

Comment: I'd like an xpath which sorts through all the "article" until i find one that has both X and Y

Comment: You can try with 
  
  "//h1/a[contains(text(),'X')]/../following-sibling::p/a[contains(text(),'Y')]/ancestor::div[@class='inner-article']"
  
  or
  
  "//h1/a[contains(text(),'X')]/../following-sibling::p/a[contains(text(),'Y')]/ancestor::div"

Comment: Fixed question, maybe now you will be able to answer.

Comment: Try extracting your element using below method using java,
  
  
  public WebElement FindItemByItsColor(string item, string color)
  {
  return driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h1/a[contains(text(),$item)]/../following-sibling::p/a[contains(text(),$color)]/ancestor::div[@class='inner-article']");
  }
  
  I can update the answer, if that solves your problem. You can also contact me with your exact problem at amitjhs2000@gmail.com, i will be more than glad to help on this.

Comment: A solution like this worked. The only thing is that your xpath didnt work properly and the "$item" was replaced with something like this " '"+item+"' "